# C++ - Not Getting Expected Output to Console

Tags: c++

I am an idiot, and I'm wondering why this code is not printing, "hello"?  If I comment out the vector.push_back(), it seems to print...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct point {
  int x,y;

  point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

int main() {

  point coord(4,4);

  vector<vector<point>> v;

  v[0].push_back(coord);

  cout << "hello" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't construct `v[0]`, you just gave an order to an entity that didn't exist. That's Undefined Behavior.

Comment: `v.at(0).push_back(coord);` would give a more useful error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector of vectors is of size 0 with absolutely nothing in it. So when you tell a nonexistent vector to push back with some data, strange things will happen to the surrounding memory. In this case (correct me if I'm wrong), you end up skipping/overwriting the region containing the instructions to call `cout <<`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct point {
    int x,y;

    point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

int main() {

    point coord(4,4);

    vector<vector<point>> v;

    v.push_back(vector<point>()); // need this one
    v[0].push_back(coord);

    cout << "hello" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```